# substraction field type time

Tags: php

I'm a beginner php-mysql programmer,, and i have some problem,, 1 of them is ....

i have a table "gangguan83" with field

```
urut_gangguan int(15) -> primary key.
lv int(10),
trip datetime,
masuk datetime,
current int(10),
ens int(10),
....
```

how can i query if my statement like this :

```
ens = (lv * 1,73 * 0,9 * current * (masuk-trip))
```

please help me.
Thanks very much before.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT lv * 1.73 * 0.9 * current * (masuk - trip) AS ens
...
```

Comment: @RageZ: [irony]programming is not a rocket science[/irony] ;-)

Comment: how about 'trip' and 'masuk' happen in different day :

Comment: trip = '2010-12-14  23:30:00' and masuk = '2010-12-13 01:00:00'.. i've try 'masuk-trip' the equal is 1.000000 , i want the equal be data of field 'lama_padam' date. Only Date hour minute, without second... Thank you.

Comment: @Asty: I cannot get what you mean.

Comment: i mean, 'masuk'-'trip'='lama_padam' with field type is datetime,,. i've tried your query above but the result was like operation with integer not ,, datetime i want. thank you.

Comment: @Asty: what result do you expect when you subtracting dates? Look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff